# Chrome extension window listener - on minimized

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I'm creating a small chrome extension, and I am having trouble figuring out what I should do to check whether a window is minimized or not.

So far I am using [chrome.tabs.onActivated](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs#event-onActivated) and [chrome.tabs.query](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs#method-query) together to listen for a tab change and it works as expected, but now my problem is I also need it to know when the browser window is minimized.

```
chrome.tabs.onActivated.addListener(function() {
    chrome.tabs.query({currentWindow: true, active: true}, function(tabs){
        //do something
    });
});
```

I have also looked at [onFocusChanged](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/windows#event-onFocusChanged) but that only seems to work with multiple browser windows.

How to check that the browser window is minimized?

Comment: What does it have to do with C++? Or anything in the title?

Comment: The title should preferrably be a short summary of the question text. As it stands now, they seem very unrelated. As Xan said, would you mind telling us if the question in the title is relevant?

Comment: sorry, i had typed the title to another question that I didn't submit, I have changed the title to fit the question.

Answer (score 0):

It's easy if you have the window ID, you can then get the [Window object](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/windows#type-Window):

```
chrome.windows.get(windowId, function(win){
  if(window.state == "minimized") {
    /* ... */
  }
});
```

If you need the current window, use `getCurrent` instead:

```
chrome.windows.getCurrent(function(win){
  if(window.state == "minimized") {
    /* ... */
  }
});
```

Comment: How would i add a listener to a window state change?

Comment: I don't think there's an event, unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

this is use code must  into background.js file :

```
//check for fcuse tab
    chrome.windows.getCurrent(function(win){
        targetWindow = win;
    });

    alert(targetWindow.state=='minimized');

    alert(targetWindow.focused);
```

---

example code:
in content.js file:

```
chrome.runtime.sendMessage({
          url: window.location.href,
          name: `${lastmessage.name}`,
          message: `${lastmessage.body}`
        });
```

and this code into background.js file:

```
var targetWindow = null;
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function (request, sender, sendResponse) {
    console.log(request.message);

    //check for fcuse tab
    chrome.windows.getCurrent(function(win){
        targetWindow = win;
    });

    alert(targetWindow.state=='minimized');

    alert(targetWindow.focused);

    //continu if 
    if(targetWindow.focused != false || targetWindow.state!='minimized')
        return 0;
})
```

Reference: https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/tabs/#type-TabStatus